# How should I retrieve the latest version of a Maven project for contract testing?

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, dependency-management, semantic-versioning

We're using Maven and Nexus to distribute components (Maven projects) inside our infrastructure. For the sake of the argument, let's say we have two teams: Team Foo and Team Bar; and that a component from Bar depends on a component from Foo.

Team Bar wants to write contract tests for checking if component `foo` behaves as expected. Those tests would run every night against the latest stable  development version of project `foo` (git master after CI). Could Team Bar write a Maven project `bar/pom.xml` that depends on the latest version of `foo`? How can we go about doing that?

We're playing with the idea of solving this through version naming. We would always name the under development version as `master-SNAPSHOT` (or something) and instead of the version label going `0.1-SNAPSHOT -> 0.1 -> 0.2-SNAPSHOT -> 0.2`, it would always go back to `master-SNAPSHOT`, like `master-SNAPSHOT -> 0.1 -> master-SNAPSHOT -> 0.2`. Contract testing project `bar` could then declare its dependency to `foo` as `com.acme:foo:master-SNAPSHOT`.

But this seems too clunky (breaks common Maven practice and stuff)... Is there a more standard practice for this kind of thing? Should we use [Maven Versions Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)? Should we inject the latest version string into the Maven project from the outside? Or maybe ditch Maven altogether?

Comment: Why is `<version>-SNAPSHOT` not suitable?

Comment: it is perfectly suitable. but it is analogous to `master-SNAPSHOT`. or isn't it?

Comment: I did not mean `<version>` literally, I meant `0.1-SNAPSHOT`, `0.2-SNAPSHOT` etc.

Comment: According to section 3.3.1 of Maven Reference Book (https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html) on project versions, `master` is not a recommended version identifier. It may be alright to use it locally, but it may prove incompatible when you distribute your artifacts via Nexus or Maven Central. Stick to numbers and dots, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

A contract test module usually has a very strong relationship to the module implementing the contract.

Thus, I recommend to evolve both modules alongside each other within a parent project.

Make `foo` and `bar` modules of a multi-module maven project. Then make `bar` depend on `foo` like you suggested yourself. Assign both the same version `${parent.version}`. This implies you use `${parent.version}-SNAPSHOT` in between releases.

Keep evolving and releasing your project like you would with a single module, preferably by using the `maven-release-plugin` on release. It will raise the versions of all modules concurrently as part of the `release:prepare` goal.